# Adelization of Shimura

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Shimura in his book *Introduction to the theory of automorphic functions* on p. 143, section 6.4, defines $$G_{\infty}=\operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbb R)$$
$$G_{\infty+}=\{x\in G_{\infty}: \det x >0\}$$ and $$G_p=\operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbb Q_p).$$ Further he defines $G_A$ as the group consisting of all elements $x=(\cdots,x_p,\cdots,x_\infty)$ of 
$$\prod_pG_p\times G_\infty$$
such that $x_p\in \mathbb Z_p$ for all but finite number of $p$.

Then he defines $G_0$ to be the archimedean part of $G_A$, that is, the set of all elements of $G_A$ whose $x_\infty$ component is $1$.

Finally he puts 
$$G_{A+}=G_0G_{\infty+}.$$

Thus last product does not make sense to me. In which group are we taking it?

Comment: If I understand your question: Shimura is identifying $G_{\infty+}$ with its image inside of $G_A$, i.e., with elements with $1$ at the non-archimedean places.

Comment: @peterag, yes, and what about $G_0$?

Comment: I'll try to get back to you later, if you're still confused, but you've written a def above for $G_0$ (elements of $G_A$ with $1$ at the archimedean place). Therefore  a typical element of $G_{A+}$ is of the form 
$$(\cdots,x_p,\cdots, x_\infty) = (\cdots, x_p,\cdots, 1)\cdot (\cdots, 1, \cdots ,x_\infty)\in G_0 G_{\infty+},$$
where $x_p$ in integral for all but finitely many $p$, and $\det x_\infty >0$. In the product above, $(\cdots, x_p,\cdots, 1)$ is a typical element of $G_0$, and $(\cdots, 1, \cdots ,x_\infty)$ is a typical element of $G_{\infty+}$.  Okay?

Comment: @peterag, Thanks, I was confused because Shimura does not mention that he embeds $G_{\infty+}$. He is a little terse sometimes.